# Download OpenTok calls locally at the end of call

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm looking to use OpenTok to record my video calls using archives. It seems as if most examples they have  on their site save their recordings online.

Is it possible to use it to record my call, then once I signal to stop archiving (still in the call), simply save and download the file locally? I would like to avoid saving my videos directly on OpenTok for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your question about the OpenTok archiving feature.

I completely understand your need to save locally due to privacy concerns.

Currently with OpenTok the way to save is to:

1. Use AmazonS3 or a Windows Azure container
2. Use OpenTok Cloud

Then you can save your file locally. You’ll have to save to online first.

Please let us know if you have any other questions or concerns.